# Data Security for SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, security

I just wanted to know what my options were for securing and encrypting data for SQL Server 2012 *standard* edition? We originally were going to use *Transparent Data Encryption* for restful encryption, but I have just [seen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.110).aspx#Enterprise_security) that feature is available from Enterprise upwards.

The requirement is to secure the data is based wholly on this is user HR data. The DB itself will be used by a web app (with security around the app added as well). I'm looking now to see purely what we can do from a database side. The data itself should be locked down to HR personnel.

If the answer is purely, "*You need to upgrade to Enterprise*", that is fine.

Comment: Why not upgrade to SQL Server 2016 SP1 and take advantage of the previously-enterprise-only security features (such as Always Encrypted, Row-Level Security, and Dynamic Data masking)? Are you stuck with 2012?